# Parse derived scientific notation

Tags: java, parsing, numbers

I'm working on FORTRAN formatted text and I get decimal numbers with the following format : `1.2345+67` `1.2345678-12`

In fact this notation is just a derived form of the scientific notation : 
`1.2345+67 = 1.2345e67`.

I would like to parse these numbers into double. **Is there a simple way for parsing these types of decimal numbers ?**

I already thought about implementing a simple method which adds an `E` or `e` before the `Double.parseDouble` call. However the loop which contains the `Double.parseDouble` is called `10e11` times, is it viable ?

Comment: You're asking us if it's viable instead of testing it yourself and finding out? In case it's not viable, I'm sure there are libraries that can parse fortran formatted values.

Comment: You're going to have to munge things somehow. Best case, you might be able to copy and massage the code from the implementation of `parseDouble`.

Comment: I already tried the alternative. For parsing  million lines the method is 1.5 to 2.5 times slower than the simple `Double.parseDouble` call on basic scientific notation. However it could be the unique solution, that's why I notified it.

Comment: @Kayaman I also tried one library [FortranFormat](https://www.ichemlabs.com/fortranformat). Even if this library works well, poor performances bring me to this point. Recently I tried to work with  [OpenFortranParser](https://github.com/OpenFortranProject/open-fortran-parser) but I still need to determine if it fits my needs even if it seems to be an overkill.